# $(APP_BUNDLE_ID) and $(APP_NAME) are not working

Tags: ios

I have created `.xcconfig` files to store `App bundle Id` and `App Name` so I can change it for development, staging and production environments.

But when I enter $(APP_BUNDLE_ID) in target identity and press enter, it change to --APP-BUNDLE-ID-, also when I use $(APP_NAME) and press enter, it change it to empty string. Am I missing something? here's my configurations

1. I created .xcconfig files that contains

```
// App Info
APP_NAME = App Name
APP_BUNDLE_ID = com.example.something
```

2. Configured a schema for each .xcconfig enviorment

Answer (score 0):

You have to set config file for each configuration in Project -> Info -> Configuration

[image]